# How can i filter the image using opencv in python

Tags: opencv, image-processing

Following images are of x-ray industrial part.

Raw:

[image: This one is the raw image]

Processed:

[image: This one is processed image]

I want to achieve the result like processed image that I have attached,
I had tried some image processing filters like Clahe,histogram EQ, but nothing is working.
please can anyone provide me some examples.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but X-ray images are not linear with respect to attenuation, as the Beer law is exponential. if you do `img=-log(img/max(img))`  you will transform it to linear attenuation, which will look like the processed image, but inverted in colors (air->black, metal->white).

Comment: @AnderBiguri thank you for the response , But the image will only get inverted it will not able to give me the result what i want.

Comment: No, the image will get _linearized_ and _inverted_. You can then invert it again, to have it linearized.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I am completely stuck because I have to give this result to my client. Is it possible for you to provide me with some source code or any alternative solution so that I can achieve the result?

Comment: I have already done it... Inverting is just doing  `img=max(img)-img`. Its 2 lines of code in total.

Comment: the provided pictures don't have enough bit depth. -- I believe it would be unethical to _give_ you a solution such that you can then sell to your client.

Comment: @crisLuengo Thank you for the response , The images which i have attached is not my client images , these are just reference images .

Comment: @VirajParshuram Good to know. I always get worried when people post images on here that seem sensitive. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one attempt using Python/OpenCV.

- Read the image as grayscale
- Add 1 to all values to avoid zeros and change the type to 16-bit integer.
- Get maximum value
- Apply Beer's Law (as suggested by Ander Biguri)
- Get max of that result
- Divide the result by the max, multiply by 255 and convert to uint8
- Invert the result
- Save the inverted result

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read the input as grayscale 
img = cv2.imread('x-ray.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Add one to value to avoid zeros and change dtype to 16 bit integer
img = cv2.add(img,1,dtype=2)

# Get max value
max = np.amax(img)
print(max)

# Apply Beer's law
result = -np.log10(img/max)

# Get max result
max_result = np.amax(result)
print(max_result)

# Divide result by max_result, multipy by 255 and convert to uint8
result = (255*cv2.divide(result, max_result)).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)

# Invert
result = 255 - result

# Save result
cv2.imwrite('x-ray-normalized.jpg', result)

cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Final Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm making one silly mistake; I'm not processing raw data; I'm processing the JPG image. That's why I am not getting the result I want. When I processed the raw data, I got the result I was looking for